# Characterization of measures such that $\frac{1}{x} \in L^1(H)$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $H$ be a finite measure on $(0,1)$. What conditions must $H$ fulfill, such that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{x} \in L^1(H),\ \ \ \frac{1}{1 - x} \in L^1(H)
\end{equation*}
I'm trying to characterize those measures. Right now I have the space of all test functions that are zero in $(0,1)\(\epsilon, 1- \epsilon)$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ as possible candidates, I yet refuse to believe that those are all choices..

Any idea?

Comment: $dH(x)=O(x^\epsilon)dx$ ($\epsilon>0$) seems a large class.

Comment: you can also take the measures which have the form $x^{-\alpha}\mathrm{d}x$ such that the problem reduces to integrability of $x^{-1-\alpha}$ in standard lebesque measure (EDIT: this is basically the same as @OliverOloa suggested)

Comment: Not too sure if I make mistake in my head, but doesn't that imply that $H$ must be absolutely continuous towards the Lebesgue measure? For example that's not true for $\delta_\epsilon(w)$, yet this measure seems to be in my class too.

Comment: Sure, my suggestion above implies that $H$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I added another requirement! I'm sorry I forgot. Please recheck.

Comment: Remark: the measures Oliver and I suggested are *not* of zero mass around $0$. they just change the weighting such that the singularity becomes integrable.

Comment: True. Is it possible we can construct something like a Schwartz space here? Edit: Yeah, Those are essentially the measures of interest. It just would be good if it didn't require a density.

Comment: To fulfill your new condition: $dH(x)=O(x^a(1-x)^b)\:dx$, ($a>0,\,b>0$).

Comment: Yeah sure, that's kinda obvious. How about the other measures?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $H$ is a positive measure. In this case, the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ will be integrable on $(0,1)$ for the measure $H$ as long as 
the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^n\cdot H\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right)$ converges. Indeed, we have the pointwise inequalities 
$$2^{n}\mathbf 1\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right)(x)\leqslant 
\mathbf 1\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right)(x)/x\leqslant 2^{n+1}\mathbf 1\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right)(x)$$
which can be integrated with respect to $H$. This gives that 
$$2^{n}H\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right)\leqslant 
\int_{\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)}\frac 1x\mathrm dH(x)\leqslant 2^{n+1}H\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right),$$
and we conclude using the equivalences 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^n\cdot H\left(\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)\right)<+\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_{\left[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}\right)}\frac 1x\mathrm dH(x)<+\infty\Leftrightarrow \int_{(0,1))}\frac 1x\mathrm dH(x)<+\infty.$$

Of course, we can derive in a similar way a necessary and sufficient condition for the integrability of $x\mapsto 1/(1-x)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate that further? It looks a little bit like the Cauchy condensation test, which we can couple with an integral test on the positive half line. I 
a) don't see yet how the inequalities you mentioned help to characterize those measures and b) don't see how this connects to integrability on (0,1), that's for $\mathbb{R}^+$, right? Or does that still work if we map \mathbb{R}^+ continuously to (0,1) ?

Comment: I have added details.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a lot clearer. Okay, that gives a criterium. This measure occurs in a represenation of another measure in a matter $\nu(A) = \mu(B) \cdot \int_{(0,1)} \max(1/x, 1/(1 - x)) H(dx)$ for what that represenation exists if the right site is finite - and I want to find conditions for what this is indeed the case.

Comment: If I look at my theorem, I might be able to assume, that if I bound my sets $A$ in a way, that I can change that integration interval from $(0,1)$ to $(\epsilon,1 - \epsilon)$ a representation in form $\int_{(\epsilon,1 - \epsilon)} \max(1/x, 1/(1 - x)) H(dx)$ always exists and is indeed always finite. I was wondering, if one could find general conditions on the speed of how fast $H$ falls to 0 at ${0,1}$ (presumption I forgot) such that the form above exists. I agree that the initial question was too general.